# Get specific field from Fieldset in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to rearrange the admin form into a custom format and order by editing the change_form.html and includes/fieldset.html.

Inside the fieldset.html, the Fieldset object is iterated to get the list of FieldLine and then AdminField objects (which contains the BoundForm for each model attribute).

Is there a way to access the BoundForm object directly without iterating?

I can get the name of the field attribute by using "{{ fieldset.fields.0 }}", but going beyond that doesn't yield anything. "{{ fieldset.fields.0.field.label_name }}" = nothing.

How can I get the label_name or other parts of a specific BoundForm without iterating over the entire fieldset?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple template tag for the purpose of returning the field at a defined key. See [Setting a Variable in the Context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context) from Django docs.

Development branch has a much easier way with `assignment_tag`, but it will only work currently if you're running from trunk or on future versions after 1.3. See: [Assignment Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags)